# How to add two lines of text inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I have the following code (the CSS are inline but once testing is done it will be moved to a designated file):

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="float: left; width: 15%; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; background: #FF00FF; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">
    <div style="text-align: center; width: 90%; padding: 0 0 0 10%; margin: 0; height: 30px; overflow: hidden;">
        URGENT CARE
        TODAYS DATE <!-- NEXT LINE CENTERED UNDERNEATH "URGENT CARE" -->
    </div>
</div>
```

displays this:

[image]

How do I modify the CSS so the two line appears like URGENT CARE of top and right below is TODAYS DATE?

Comment: can you explain a little bit more what you want to achieve? it is not clear.

Comment: And what about using `<br />` tag after 'Care'?

Comment: the current date can not be retrieved with html / css, you'd need to do it client side with js or server side with php / asp.net or similar

Comment: @andrew Thank you. It was a placeholder anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some Jquery for That

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/zp0q1yrx/

[image]

**Jquery**

```
var currtime = new Date();
var currdate = new Date();

currdate = (currdate.getMonth()+ 1) + '/' + currdate.getDate() + '/' + currdate.getFullYear(); 

currtime = (currtime.getHours() + ":"+ currtime.getMinutes());

$("#message").html("");
$("#message").html( "URGENT CARE<br />" + currdate + " " + currtime);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have already does the job, except that you need to change the line-height to 15px for the 3rd div. BTW, you're missing a closing `</div>` tag for the 1st element ... That's what you asked about ...

```
<div style="... "> 
    <div style="...">
        <div style="...line-height: 15px">
          URGENT CARE
          TODAY'S DATE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BUT...

Presumably you'll want to be able to reuse this code dynamically for other departments (pediatrics, radiology, etc). Some names might be longer than others & have to wrap, breaking your hard-coded 30px height limitation and the centering. Alternatively, you can cut them off w/`text-overflow:ellipses`

Also, presumably you will eventually want to display the actual date dynamically (from a server or from the browser) as other people have already suggested. Will it fit in the given width? Do you want to include only the date or a label first? `"Today's Date: 1/1/2015"`?

To address these issues, each line of text should be wrapped in an element with a unique ID or class so it's accessible in code. Could be a `<div>` or a `<span>` displayed as a block.

What you have already seems to work fine just changing the line height, but the height is fixed. Below I've wrapped the text & changed the divs to `height:auto;` where appropriate.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajaaf41g/3/

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; "> 
    <div style="float: left; width: 15%; height: auto; line-height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; background: #FF00FF; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 90%; padding: 0 0 0 10%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; line-height: 15px; background-color:#ff00ff">
          <span id="dept_name" class="pretty_span">REALLY LONG MEDICAL DEPARTMENT NAME</span>
          <span id="todays_date" class="pretty_span">TODAYS DATE</span> <!-- NEXT LINE CENTERED UNDERNEATH "URGENT CARE" -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might also consider making dept name & date a slightly different size & color, to differentiate them. Rather than have them centered in a jumble in case the dept name has to wrap, left-align them to each other, but center them in the parent div. Use margins to separate them from each other & the edges of the parent div. You could keep fixed pixel values for `font-size` or use `em` for dynamic sizing.

CSS:

```
.pretty_span{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

#dept_name{
    margin: 0.6em 0 0.6em 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#todays_date{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}
```

Comment: points for taking flexibility/extensibility into account. OP's issue is really line height, but without demo and data samples, this answer helps cover the most common obstacles that will probably be encountered next by OP, preventing re-edits and comment questions under this answer.

Comment: Wow... thank you. This really does the job really well!

Answer (score 1):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/o1xubLq8/

Simply:

1. Change `line-height` to `15px`
2. Add `<br/>` in-between the two text portions.

Comment: Did you try stack snippets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want one on top of the another you may want this:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="float: left; width: 15%; height: 60px; line-height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; background: #FF00FF; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">
    <div style="text-align: center; width: 90%; padding: 0 0 0 10%; margin: 0; height: 60px; overflow: hidden;">
        URGENT CARE
        TODAYS DATE <!-- NEXT LINE CENTERED UNDERNEATH "URGENT CARE" -->
    </div>
</div>
```